# Communicating between Processes using Pipes in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, ipc

I am writing two programs

- First program send text messages to second program.
- The second program writes all the messages to a specified file. Once the second program terminates then it needs to inform first program that it is going to close or terminate.

If the second program is not up then user should not be allowed to send messages from first program. If user opens the second program again then first program needs to allow sending messages. If the first program is not up or closing then second program needs to be also closed automatically.

I tried to write the code but I am not able to get all the scenario. In this code, I am able to send a text and save a text in a file. After that, I am not able to do

First Program code is Here :

```
public void ThreadStartClient(object obj)
{

        ManualResetEvent syncServer = (ManualResetEvent)obj;

        using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream("PipeTo"))
        {

            pipeStream.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("[First program] Pipe Connection established");
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeStream))
            {
                sw.AutoFlush = true;
                string message;
                Console.WriteLine("Please type a message and press [ENTER], or type 'quit' to exit the program");
                while ((message = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (message == "quit")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                       // pipeStream.Connect();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Second Program code is here :

```
 public void ThreadStartServer()
    {
        using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipeTo"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Second program] Pipe Created");
            pipeStream.WaitForConnection();
            Console.WriteLine("[Second program] Pipe connection established");
            StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("C:\\ServerEXE\\DemoTest.txt", true);


            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
            {
                string message;
                while ((message = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    sw1.WriteLine(message);
                    sw1.Flush();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", message);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Connection lost");
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Typically you should try and minimize the code you post by trying to determine where the fault could be coming from. Additionally your question is a bit vague since you only mention that it stops working, without detail as to what it does when it fails. For example, are both programs still running? Is "Connection lost" printed?

Comment: Hi @Guvante...This code is working fine. But, I am not able to write complete program. Through this program I can send message from 1st program and 2nd program able to save in a file. For the further steps I need help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the second program create a named [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) and set its state to signaled. The first program can test the event to see if it's signaled. If it is, then it can send the message.

In the first program, you write:

```
private EventWaitHandle SendMessageEvent;
private const string WaitHandleName = "UniqueNameForThisHandle";

void InitializeWaitHandle()
{
    SendMessageEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, WaitHandleName);
}
```

And, to send a message, you first check the wait handle:

```
if (SendMessageEvent.WaitOne(0))
{
    // event is signaled, so send the message
}
```

The second program opens the wait handle and sets its state to signaled:

```
void InitializeWaitHandle()
{
    SendMessageEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, WaitHandleName);
    SendMessageEvent.Set();
}
```

When the second program shuts down, or if you don't want it receiving messages, just call `Reset`:

```
SendMessageEvent.Reset();
```

Use the same name for the wait handle in both programs. But use a name that's unlikely to be used by other programs. Otherwise you'll have a name collision.

Comment: I recommend using a GUID for the name, that makes a collision highly unlikely.